# ffmpeg Windows split 1 video to chunks with random length (no re-encode)

Tags: ffmpeg, random

i have 1 big video file and i need to split it to random length chunks without re-encode.

for example chunks from 130 to 240 seconds.

for windows ffmpeg

tried this and .... nothing in output folder.

```
$ times=$(ruby -e 's=[]; d=0; while d < 150 do t=rand(15..50); s << (d+t); d=d+t end; puts s.join(",")')
$ echo $times
15,53,96,124,168
$ ffmpeg -i lutherceleb.mp4 -f segment -segment_times $times -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 OUTPUT%d.mp4
```

thanks you.

Comment: did it just googled 10 minutes. zero in coding)

Comment: but it set just 1 random number for all chunks. set /a rand=%random% %% 10-5 echo %rand% for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c copy -map 0 -segment_time "%rand%" -f segment "out/%%3d %%~na.mp4

Comment: It sounds like these comments would be better as edits to your original question.